# Failure in inner @Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class) rolls back entire outside persistence

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a job method in a class-annotated `@Transactional`. This job method calls inner methods for persistence of individual records. If I simulate an error in the following inner `update()` method somewhere in the middle of my result set processing, I see that all successful records **before/after** this exception do **not** get saved after job completion. Why is that? All outside persistence should remain, with the exception of the individual record that failed. The inner `update` alone has `rollbackFor`.

```
@Service("mailService")
@Transactional
@EnableScheduling
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

  @Override
  @Scheduled(cron = "${mail.cron.pubmed.autosynch.job}")
  public void autoSynchPubMedJob() {
     //... Fetch result set
     for (Result r: resultset) {
        try {
           pubService.updatePublication(r);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // Silently log and continue
           log.error("Error on record: ", e);
        }
     }
  }
```

The `updatePublication` method, this is the one with `rollbackFor`:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void updatePublication(Publication publication) throws Exception {
    dao.update1(..);
    dao.update2(..);
    // Simulate exception for a specific record for testing
    if (publication.getId() == 123) {
       throw new Exception("Test Exception");
    }
}
```

Result: **no** successful data persisted at all at the end of job completion. There should be partial persistence (for other successful records).
When I remove this Exception simulation, all data is successfully persisted at the end. Also, all data is persisted if I remove the inner call's `rollbackFor`.

Answer (score 1):

Probaby because it uses existing transaction. Try opening a new one with  `propagation = REQUIRES_NEW`.

Note: New transaction won't be opened if you call the method from the same service. You should use either self-reference call or extract logic to another `@Service`.

Comment: Thanks. The inner call is in another Service class, `PublicationService` (not `MailService`), so that shouldn't be a problem. However, when I added `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` to the inner PublicationService method, I started getting this new error: `PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: myapp.Publication`

Comment: Ah, you probably fetched an object inside first transaction and then passed it to the method in new service. It is not optimal, but fetching it again in the new transaction would solve the problem.

Comment: Are there any solutions to this issue? I can't really bring the fetch under this service method. The object gets modified much earlier, and it's that modified object that I need to persist close to the end. Do I need to move the Class's @Transactional out of its current place?

Comment: A detached entity is an object that has the same ID as an entity in the persistence store but is no longer part of a persistence context.

You could remove Class's @Transactional, but it will not help much.

So what you would want is that you take something from the transaction, and something rollback, which I think is impossible with the default PersistenceContext. What I would do, is: save an object in autoSynchPubMedJob, pass the identifier to updatePublication, get the object there, modify it, and save.